# Attach file to Freeform submission

Tags: emails, plugin-freeform, modules, freeform

I'm building a form that allows a user the ability to attach their authored assets onto the form submission.

I have a custom module that's hooking into `MailerService` in Freeform and looking up the asset that's been selected.

```php
Event::on(
            MailerService::class,
            MailerService::EVENT_BEFORE_SEND,
            function (SendEmailEvent $event) {

                $formHandle = 'apply';
                if ($event->getForm()->getHandle() != $formHandle) {
                    return false;
                }
                // hardcoding the asset id for testing
                $document = Asset::find()->id(23438)->one();
                
                $extension = pathinfo($document->filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                $spaces = new Spaces(App::env('SPACES_API_KEY'), App::env('SPACES_SECRET'));
                $space = $spaces->space(App::env('SPACES_BUCKET'));
                
                $file = $space->file($document->filename);
                $file->download(CRAFT_BASE_PATH . '/applications/' . $document->filename);
                $message = $event->getMessage();

                $message->attach(CRAFT_BASE_PATH . '/applications/' . $document->filename, [
                    'fileName' => "document.$extension",
                    'contentType' => FileHelper::getMimeType($document),
                ]);
            }
        );
```

however, Freeform tells me it failed to send the email notification with error

`finfo_file(my file copy): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

where am I going wrong?

removing the `$message->attach` and the email sends as normal, just without the attachment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got this working. I was following the example from Craft Commerce on the `$message->attach()` method but all I needed really was `$message->attach($filename);`

Full module snippet for this is

```php
Event::on(
            MailerService::class,
            MailerService::EVENT_BEFORE_SEND,
            function (SendEmailEvent $event) {
                $form = $event->getForm();

                if ($form->getName() != self::APPLICATION_FORM) {
                    return false;
                }

                $existingDoc = $event->getForm()->get('existingDoc')->getValue();

                if (!empty($existingDoc)) {
                    $doc = Asset::find()->id($existingDoc)->one();

                    $spaces = new Spaces(App::env('SPACES_API_KEY'), App::env('SPACES_SECRET'));
                    $space = $spaces->space(App::env('SPACES_BUCKET'));

                    $file = $space->file($doc->filename);
                    $filename = CRAFT_BASE_PATH . '/applications/' . $doc->filename;
                    $file->download($filename);

                    $message = $event->getMessage();
                    $message->attach($filename);
                }
            }
        );
```

will likely batch into a Queue job now as well to make the response snappier.